# Can I update multiple columns using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I currently am using existing code that has

```
Sql.Append("UPDATE Store SET" +
"LogoAlign='" + (String.Compare(drpLogoAlign.SelectedValue, String.Empty) == 0 ? "NULL" : "'" + drpLogoAlign.SelectedValue + "'") +
"', Height='" + DB.QuerySafeDisplayHTML(txtHeight.Text.ToString()) +
"', Width='" + DB.QuerySafeDisplayHTML(txtWidth.Text.ToString()) +
```

and it goes on like that for all the columns in the table that it is updating. I would like to know if it would be better using LINQ, easier, more beneficial, and if so how would I go about doing it?

Thanks

Comment: **warning** your code is susceptible to sql injection attacks.

Comment: what are you using linq to sql or ef?

Comment: LINQ itself does not do updates, only queries. One of the ORM libs might help you out here if you bind a proper object to the GUI first.

Comment: I realize that the code is vulnerable to sql injection, would linq offer protection from it?
I want to use linq for sql

Comment: @HenkHolterman While LINQ is only about querying, the various providers including LINQ to SQL, Entity Framework, LINQ to nHibernate, etc. do support updates.

Comment: @JimWooley - depends how/where you draw the boundaries. Linq-to-objects has no updating whatsoever. The ORMs do, all with their own non-standard API.

Comment: @JoeW LINQ to SQL by default eliminates SQL Injection. There are ways of getting around it and forcing injection, but it protects you out of the box. See http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/Does-LINQ-to-SQL-eliminate-the-possibility-of-SQL-Injection

Comment: @HenkHolterman true. I typically start my discussions of LINQ by saying that it has NOTHING to do with databases. It's an abstraction for querying over set based operations. It would be nice if the updates could be standardized, but that would mean too many breaking changes for existing code at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Linq To Entity you can just get all the `Store` than loop through them to change the value and use the Entity to `SaveChanges`.

For example:

```
using (TestDBEntities ctx = new TestDBEntities())
{
    var allStore = ctx.Stores;
    foreach(var store in allStore)
    {
        store.LogoAlign = (String.Compare(drpLogoAlign.SelectedValue, String.Empty) == 0 ? "NULL" : "'" + drpLogoAlign.SelectedValue + "'");
        store.Height = txtHeight.Text.ToString();
    }
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

You can do the same with Linq To Sql with the DataContext.

```
using (TestDataContext ctx = new TestDataContext())
{
    var allStore = ctx.Stores;
    foreach(var store in allStore)
    {
        store.LogoAlign = (String.Compare(drpLogoAlign.SelectedValue, String.Empty) == 0 ? "NULL" : "'" + drpLogoAlign.SelectedValue + "'");
        store.Height = txtHeight.Text.ToString();
    }
    ctx.SubmitChanges();
}
```

But, if you want to be more performance, I think it should be in a **[stored procedure](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/entity-framework-mapping-to-stored-procedure)**, this way you won't need to get all the data before updating.

Comment: Thank you, I am taking your advice and just going to make a stored procedure, I will mark you answer as the one I used. Thanks for your help